# angular js modal popup and grid not working together

Tags: angularjs, popup

Below are my html and js code if i use the below angular js refrence 1.3.0 beta i am able to load the grid with data but my popup doesnt load, and if i try to remove the reference with other version my popup loads but grid dosent
popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body ng-app>   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.5/angular.js"></script>
     <!--<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.1/angular.min.js"></script>-->

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.0rc1/angular-route.min.js"></script>   
    <script src="https://rawgit.com/dwmkerr/angular-modal-service/master/dst/angular-modal-service.js"></script>

    <script src="popup.js"></script>

    <link href="StyleSheet1.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <div class="container"  ng-controller="TestCtrl" ng-init="firstCall()">

        <h3>Angular Modal Service</h3>
        <a class="btn btn-default" ng-app="app" ng-click="show()">Show a Modal</a>
        <p>{{message}}</p>

        <!-- The actual modal template, just a bit o bootstrap -->
        <script type="text/ng-template" id="modal.html">
            <div class="modal fade">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" ng-click="close('Cancel')" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>                          
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <div>
                                <div>
                                    Defect Area:
                                    <select ng-model="details.DefectArea">
                                        <option value="" disabled="disabled" selected="selected"></option>
                                        <option value="Scheduler">Scheduler</option>
                                        <option value="ShopApp">ShopApp</option>
                                        <option value="Process Claims">Process Claims</option>
                                        <option value="TR Workbench">TR Workbench</option>
                                        <option value="QFC Workbench">QFC Workbench</option>
                                        <option value="WS Workbench">WS Workbench</option>
                                        <option value="SysAdmin">SysAdmin</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                                <hr />
                                <div>
                                    Defect Summary:
                                    <input type="text" style="height:28px;width:27%" ; placeholder="" ng-model="details.DefectSummary">

                                </div>
                                <hr />
                                <div>
                                    Defect Details:
                                    <input type="text" style="height:28px;width:50%" ;placeholder="" ng-model="details.DefectDetails">
                                </div>
                                <hr />
                                <input type="button" ng-click="SendData(details)" value="Add" />
                            </div>
                        </div>                       
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </script>
        <h4 style="color:blueviolet">{{value}}</h4>
        <div class="table-responsive com-table">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th width="5%" style="background-color:cadetblue" ;>DefectArea</th>
                        <th width="15%" style="background-color:cadetblue" ;> DefectSummary</th>
                        <th width="15%" style="background-color:cadetblue" ;>DefectDetails</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                    <tr ng-repeat="CU in DefectList" style="background-color:darkgray" ;>
                        <td width="5%"><span ng-bind=CU.DefectName></span></td>
                        <td width="15%"><span ng-bind=DefectSummary></span></td>
                        <td width="15%"><span ng-bind=CU.DefectDetails></span></td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

            <div class="collapse">
                <div class="well">
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
        <hr />

    </div>
</body>
</html>


Popup.js
var app = angular.module('app', ['angularModalService']);

app.controller('TestCtrl', function ($scope, ModalService) {

    $scope.show = function () {
        ModalService.showModal({
            templateUrl: 'modal.html',
            controller: "ModalController"
        }).then(function (modal) {
            modal.element.modal();
            modal.close.then(function (result) {
                $scope.message = "You said " + result;
            });
        });
    };

});

app.controller('ModalController', function ($scope, close) {

    $scope.close = function (result) {
        close(result, 500); // close, but give 500ms for bootstrap to animate
    };

});
var TestCtrl = function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.firstCall = function () {

        $http({
            url: "NewRoute/getDataForAngularGrid",
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'GET',
            data: '',
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }).success(function (response) {
            debugger;
            $scope.DefectList = response;
        })
           .error(function (error) {
               alert(error);
           });
    }
    $scope.SendData = function (Data) {
        var GetAll1 = new Object();
        GetAll1.DefectName = Data.DefectArea;
        GetAll1.DefectSummary = Data.DefectSummary;
        GetAll1.DefectDetails = Data.DefectDetails;
        $scope.IsToBeShown = true;
        $http({
            url: "NewRoute/firstCall",
            dataType: 'json',
            method: 'POST',
            data: GetAll1,
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json"
            }
        }).success(function (response) {
            $scope.value = response;
            $scope.firstCall;
        })
           .error(function (error) {
               alert(error);
           });
    }

};
```

Comment: you need to say where you stuck up . Try to produce a plunker or fiddle which will help you to get some answers and Go through this Instructions  [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @Prasad could you please check your company site, which has XSS vulnerability in INITIATE REGISTRATION where it returns the server side things when the form is submitted , I thought of letting u know